# Ошибка при запуске .exe файла после компиляции .py в .exe

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe, cx-oracle

Если запускать мой скрипт как .py файл, то всё работает. После я попыталась скомпилировать и всё удачно завершилось. Она даже запускается, но при нажатии кнопок которые должны подключиться к базе, выдаёт такие ошибки:  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне кажется что дело в не правильном преобразовании .py в .exe т.к. для работы модуля cx_Oracle нужно руками добавлять вот эти .dll файлы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пыталась добавлять эти .dll в папку из которой компилировала файл, но это не помогло.
Подскажите что я делаю не так, спасибо

Comment: В ошибке написано, что оно не может найти 64-битный драйвер, а тот, который вы ему предлагаете имеет не ту архитектуру.

Answer (score 0):

Я разобралась, что бы скрипт не просил 64х битную версию, нужно эти .dll файлы поместить в папку где находятся .dll файлы клиента оракла. Тогда всё будет работать. Работать с бд через проги по типу (Toad for Oracle 14.2 Trial (32-bit)) тоже можно всё хорошо, но бывают проги которым нужны только .dll с которыми они работа раньше. Поэтому стоит закинуть в ручную эти 3 .dll файла в папку вашего скомпилированного скрипта (С:(ваша папка)\dist(ваша папка))
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
И всё будет работать! удачи